# Visualizar con buen formato el PDF generado con JAVA

Tags: java, pdf, impresión

Buenas, tengo una aplicación hecha sobre un concesionario, tengo un jtabbedpane con una pestaña informes donde realizo consultas o por código de cliente o por matricula y lo visualizo en un texArea de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que al darle al botón imprimir y generar un PDF con el texto que recojo del textArea, me muestra el contenido de esta, pero todo en una linea, sin aplicar el formato que quiero.

**Imagen del PDF generado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de la clase Imprimir:**

```
public class ImprimirPDF
{  
   public Font fuenteInforme = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 10);
   public PrintJob pj;
   public Graphics paginaInforme;

    public ImprimirPDF()
    {
        pj = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getPrintJob(new Frame(), "Informe", null);
    }

    public void realizarImpresion(String textoImprimir)
    {
        try
        {
            paginaInforme = pj.getGraphics();           
            paginaInforme.setFont(fuenteInforme);
            paginaInforme.setColor(Color.black);

            paginaInforme.drawString(textoImprimir, 60, 80);            

            paginaInforme.dispose();
            pj.end();
        }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impresión cancelada");}
    }    
}
```

Comment: Por lo visto estás armando el PDF a mano. Considera que esto va a causar un terrible dolor al momento de hacer el mantenimiento. Te recomiendo usar un reporteador como Jasper Reports que te facilitará tanto el mantenimiento como la generación del PDF.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, puedes guiarme un poco a utilizar eso?

Comment: Revisa el tutorial oficial en línea: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial Es algo extenso pero te ayudará mucho. Ojo que esto no saldrá en media o una hora, requiere pruebas y sobretodo paciencia.

Comment: Vale gracias, le echare un buen ojo! Saludos!